# can't resolve stripe - import axios from axios NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a checkout session but I get an error message and one line is highlighted in the log. I'm not sure why it's doing this because they are both installed and present in my package.json. Has something changed? The .env variables are being logged in the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"Module not found: Can't resolve 'stripe'

> 1 | const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
> |               ^"

http://localhost:3000/api/createStripeSession 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
import axios from axios
```

This is the code

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);


export default async  (req,res) =>  {
    const {item} = req.body;
  console.log(item);
    const transformedItem ={
    price_data: {
        currency: 'gbp',
        product_data: {
         images:   [item.image],
         name: item.name,
        },
        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
    },
    description: item.description,
    quantity: item.quantity,
}

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: 'payment',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
        transformedItem,
      ],
     
success_url: 'https://localhost:3000/Success',
  cancel_url: 'https://localhost:3000/Cancel',
metadata: {
    images: JSON.stringify(item.map((i)=> i.image)) ,
},
});
res.status(200).json({id: session.id})

};
```

The function

```
const createCheckOutSession = async () => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    
    
    const checkoutSession = await axios.post('/api/createStripeSession', {
      item: item,
    });


    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id,
});
if (result.error) {
    alert(result.error.message);
}
};


const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "Apple AirPods",
    description: "Latest Apple AirPods.",
    image: "/searching.png",
    quantity: 0,
    price: 10,
  });

  const cartChange = (value) => {
    setItem({ ...item, quantity: Math.max(0, value) });
  };
```

package json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.24.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  }
}
```

I hope this is clear, first time working with stripe in nextjs

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: just added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [`stripe-node` package](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), which facilitates server-side API requests (like creating a Checkout Session).

```
npm install stripe --save
```

Comment: Thank you, amazed I missed that. Now I'm getting an internal 500 server error with an error 'invalid array'. Any ideas?

Comment: Best guess is this line: `JSON.stringify(item.map((i)=> i.image))`. From what I can tell, your `item` variable is an Object and `.map` is a method on the Array prorotype.